# components get black in android 2.3 version

Tags: android

My layout has problem that describe in the image below

```
 <EditText
            android:id="@+id/txtname"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/background"
            android:hint="Name"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColor="#414141" >
```

here is background.xml file is

```
<stroke
    android:width="0.5dp"
    android:color="#414141" />

<corners android:radius="5dp" />
```

Here is my snapshot:

[image: Snapshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hey this kind of problem i faced that and you should try this code below

background.xml

```
<solid android:color="#ffffff" />

<stroke
    android:width="0.5dp"
    android:color="#414141" />

<corners android:radius="5dp" />
```

here is your edit text

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtname"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/background"
        android:hint="Name"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColor="#414141" >
```